# How to Pass UserName & Password in Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, odata

I created OData Services with Custom Authentication, How to pass the UserName & Password in Ajax. Note that without having security below code working fine.

Please help on this

Below is my Code

```
var _url = "http://localhost:49497/DataService.svc/Mst_User?$filter=Us_Name eq 'Basit' and Us_Password eq 's'&$format=json";

$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: _url,
                timeout: 10000,
                async: true,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) 
                    debugger;
                    //                   
                    if (data.d.length > 0 && data.d[0].Us_Admin == 1) {


                        var Adminrole = data.d[0].Us_AdminModule
                        var UsNo = data.d[0].Us_No


                    } else {
                        Alter(‘Login Failed’)
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) { // flow always comes in error callback even url returns true and this is the issue.
                        Alter(‘Login Failed’)
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Thanks
Basit

Comment: Some would argue that you should not include the username and password as query params even when you are using HTTPS. The reason being that many web servers record the full url in the access logs. It is considered better practice to send the username and password either as a request header or as POST data.

Comment: `application/jsonp` isn't a registered MIME type (the JSONP format is a JavaScript program so would be `application/javascript`), but since you are making a GET request there is no request body to describe the content-type of anyway.